# RSA Encryption with unknown format

Tags: android, string, rsa

What can be achieved to this encrypted format?

My android app send encrypted messages to the c# server but server want encrypted messages actually like this unknown format`chinese words`.

[![Unknown encrypted format ][1]][1]

But android encrypt messages like this format (`on7vQhgNeVDVDu4evL0HZ5UbC2C1oZdamfU9XBLGZQZ13MLQKu2speIWNaldsfcGfPS`)

I use RSA algorithm with same public/private keys in c sharp and android.
where am i interrupted?

Something wrong with this approach with this unknown format.

Its seems android have problem with class of encryption I don't know what else need to use for this issue

Thank you for advice

Android code

```
          public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acti);
    try {
        generateKey();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  static void generateKey() throws Exception {



    String modulusString = "tx94IV9NAutFU1HQjXmkLzknJ5vatOFyhD90Un3u5oiOc4e9fT1bsM0af3OqNMCTRLPuQJ2JQokY+3T0icJqHgG/aHvbmvDvRKn2QrVxAFt8EN6jp/S6+dRe1B/6eJbVRJJpeekLslqGqdQgr+5ocD+ZPjiE2iL6sGGyAYz+lOJtSr9N4ZcD4kNikI3J9kZDNO78rEqQuX7flh0RS79N63MJ9xX9fBuqHFIud3KKKbqHiASQoaU1rWqZ2VIdqfXzreZMYHpHYioVzyrbk/wdQQV2ibmJFAsa5aiKSP+g9rF4xYoPAistePDwn4O+wARGlMsu7RYVAIeUM77l+w6ugw==";
    String ExponentString = "AQAB";
    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(modulusString.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(ExponentString.getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT);
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
    BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);


    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    String INPUT = "GAVDOOL";

    RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
    PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

  //  byte[] plainBytes = clearTextPassword.getBytes();
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(INPUT.getBytes());
    String encryptedStringBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    System.out.println("Encrypted?????"+encryptedStringBase64);
    System.out.println(encryptedStringBase64.length());

          }
           }
```

Unknown encrypted format, see this at [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF84B.jpg

Comment: Your 'reference tutorial' does not contain the misuse of `ready()` in your code, but there is no reason to use arbitrary Internet junk when there are plenty of tutorials provided by Oracle. I suggest you get your code working *without* SSL first, as it has problems that have nothing to do with SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED,

I finally changed  server code and remove the Encoding.Unicode part and now this issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The method encrypt(data) is never called? Seems you have some unreachable code...

Comment: Add a method call for encrypt(data) in onClick maybe take you one step further? I don't know if you have coded in Java/Android before but maybe start doing a Java tutorial before digging into this Android stuff. It could help you a lot.

Comment: That is because encrypt(data) is a method of the class ENC. You need something like ENC enc = new ENC(); enc.encrypt(data); . Also this will set the text of the textfield to the public key, not the ciphertext. Please learn some basic java/programming/OO skills before trying something like this... After that you should be able to spot these errors easily.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not gonna do all the coding work for you, that is not the goal of this site. Just take some time to learn the basic (Android) programming skills or hire an external programmer to do the work for you (like https://bountify.co/).